# Summing Multiple Columns using SAS

Tags: sas

I want to add multiple columns using SAS.

Data Have:

```
D C1 C2 C3 C4 C5.....   
J 01 02 00 04 15 
F 05 00 09 11 00  
M 12 14 88 00 00
A 55 03 00 00 00  
M 67 00 00 00 00
```

I don't want to do this

Data Want;

```
Set Have;  
N1 = C1;  
N2 = C1+C2;  
N3 = C1+C2+C3;  
N4 = C1+C2+C3+C4; 
N5 = C1+C2+C3+C4+C5;
Keep N:    
Run;
```

want my table to look like this.

Data table Want

```
D N1  N2  N3  N4  N5.....   
J 01  03  03  07  22 
F 05  05  14  25  00  
M 12  26  114 00  00
A 55  58  00  00  00  
M 67  00  00  00  00
```

Note that I will have a lot of columns and the number will vary. I need a dynamic code which will automatically count the number of columns and perform the calculation. I need the bottom triangle to stay 0 and not keep adding it up. It still need to perform if there is zero value like in the case of (J,C3) in the example. I also need it to keep the order. Cannot change the order of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with arrays.

First generate some fake data.  This has 100 variables and 100 observarions.

```
data have;
array C[100];
do i=1 to 100;
    do j=1 to 100;
        c[j] = j;
    end;
    output;
end;
drop i j;
run;
```

Now, get a count of the numeric variables:

```
data _null_;
set have;
array x[*] _numeric_;
call symput("nVar",dim(x));
stop;
run;

%put Number Variables = &nVar;
```

This tells me `Number Variables = 100` -- all good.

Now use a Data Step to do your sums.

```
data want;
set have nobs=nobs;
array x[&nVar] _numeric_;
array N[&nVar];

do i=1 to &nVar;
    do j=1 to i;
        if j <= (nobs - _n_ + 1) then
           N[i] = sum(N[i],x[j]);
        else 
           N[i] = 0; /*Change to missing (.) if needed*/
    end;
end;

keep N:;
run;
```

Comment: You can do it with one do loop.  `n(1)=x(1); do i=2 to dim(n); n(i)=sum(x(i),n(i-1)); end;`

Comment: @DomPazz. Thank you very much. I tried this code. It worked for what I explained. I made a mistake however and need to update my question if you want to have a look again.

Comment: @Tom. Thank you very much. I tried this code. It worked for what I explained. I made a mistake however and need to update my question if you want to have a look again.

Comment: @Myburge, updated by adding a check to ensure you are in the upper left triangle.  Also made the input data square.

Comment: @DomPazz thank you. Code was really useful. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 5):

sas sum function can take range of variables like this:

```
data work;
    c1=1;
    c2=2;
    c3=3;
    n=sum(of c1-c3);
run;
```

Comment: I actually still need to keep N1, N2, N3 and N4. But in my case it will go to adding like 100 columns like this. So don't want to hard code it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

```
data c;
   infile cards firstobs=2;
   length id $1;
   array C[5];
   input (_all_)(:);
   cards;
D C1 C2 C3 C4 C5   
J 01 02 00 04 15 
F 05 00 09 11  .  
M 12 14 88  .  .
A 55 03  .  .  .  
M 67  .  .  .  .
;;;;
   run;
data score;
   retain _type_ 'SCORE';
   length _name_ $32;
   if 0 then set c;
   array c[*] c:;
   do n = 1 to dim(c);
      _name_ = cats('N',n);
      c[n] = 1;
      output;
      end;
   drop n;
   stop;
   run;
proc score data=c score=score out=new;
   var c:;
   run;
```

[image]

This is a good opportunity to learn PROC SCORE. You use the input data to create the simple custom scoring data, run proc score and done.

```
data c;
   input C1-C4;
   cards;
01 02 03 04  
05 06 09 11  
12 14 01 02 
;;;;
   run;
data score;
   retain _type_ 'SCORE';
   length _name_ $32;
   if 0 then set c;
   array c[*] c:;
   do n = 1 to dim(c);
      _name_ = cats('N',n);
      c[n] = 1;
      output;
      end;
   drop n;
   stop;
   run;
proc score data=c score=score out=new;
   var c:;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have to update my question. Since I made a mistake. Please take a look again.

Comment: A proper triangular matrix does not use zeros it uses missing values.  That has been part of your problem from the beginning.  Just fix that.

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling to type the triangle properly and was using the 0 as placeholders. Trying this code now.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Appreciate it. My code so much better than before.